# Is there a listener like facility in web service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, web-applications

I am a newbie to Spring Boot and REST concepts, I am not sure how to implement a listener kind of functionality in my web application.
I am working on a Spring Boot web application that needs to send data every hour to a third party web application. My web app "receives" a PUT call with JSON string body from outside. I am required to register the incoming Person details and start a thread (I am guessing if this is correct) that sends certain data every hour via POST/PUT to the 3rd party web application. Before sending details each time I need to do a GET call to the 3rd party web application to ensure the person is still active in the 3rd party web application.

Below is the pseudo logic I am thinking of.

1. My web application receives PUT call from 3rd party web application.
2. Parse JSON and register Person. (I am able to do till this step)
3. In a while loop, check if Person is active in 3rd party web application (GET call)
4. If active, then send details to 3rd party web application (PUT call)
5. Else stop sending details.

I need help on how to implement a listener kind of facility in my web application.
EDIT: I came across the concept of Java's ExecutorService and Thread Pool.

Comment: What does any of that pseudo logic have to do with a listener?

Comment: I would recommend a message based solution that uses Rabbit MQ.  Keep those threads and details out of your REST services.  They do not belong there.

Comment: @duffymo due to 3rd party web application (my client org) being involved I do not have a say in asking them for Rabbit MQ changes. I believe I need to create new thread for each incoming requests and have a listener that checks for Person's active status

Comment: Of course you have a choice.  Your belief involves your assumption of how to solve this problem.  I'm suggesting that there's another way.  Until you implement something you have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

I think through feign client you can do it easily.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Comment: Thanks for the lead. I also came across the concept of Java's ExecutorService and Thread pool. I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

After further research I came across Java's Executor Service and Thread Pool. I believe this will serve my purpose